# Removing notification from notification center windows 10

Tags: python, winapi, windows-10, toast, win32gui

I've been using win32api in Python3 to create a Windows 10 application that supports toast notifications.

I already have a system tray icon for my app, I'm adding toast notifications using the following code

```
def show_toast(self,msg,title):
        flags = win32gui.NIF_ICON | win32gui.NIF_MESSAGE | win32gui.NIF_TIP
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0, flags, win32con.WM_USER + 20, self.hicon, 
            "SpotiFind")
        win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_MODIFY, (self.hwnd, 0, 
            win32gui.NIF_INFO,
            win32con.WM_USER + 20,
            self.hicon, "Balloon Tooltip", msg, 200, title))
```

All works well but the notification stays in the notification area and I want to delete it automatically... according to MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-_notifyicondataa)

> To remove a balloon notification, specify NIF_INFO and provide an empty string through szInfo.

So I've tried the following

```
def _destroy_toast(self):
    win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_MODIFY, (self.hwnd, 0, 
            win32gui.NIF_INFO,
            win32con.WM_USER + 20,
            self.hicon, "Balloon Tooltip", "", 200, ""))
```

This does nothing...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Use `Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, nid)` The tabs are in the wrong place in your post.

Comment: Tabs are due to SO requirements.. but there's not NIM_DELETE in the snippet... NIM_DELETE is used to delete the ICON and I want to keep the icon (system tray) and just remove the toast notification from the notification area..

Comment: I can't duplicate the described behavior with `NIM_MODIFY` , it removes the toast in my Win10

Comment: The toast disappears by itself. but it stays in the notification area. [link](https://imgur.com/a/2bs4bVQ) I want it to be removed from the windows 10 notification area when the toast is done...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement this in C# and also had problems with it. The way that works for me is:

```
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, nid)
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_CREATE, nid)
```

During deletion, all notifications will be cleared, both active and snoozed.